# Android Studio Creating subdir when compiling aar

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I got two aar files from customer to be included into my project. So as usual in build.gralde i added `compile (name: 'myaarfile-1.1.1', ext: 'aar')` and compile `(name: 'mysecondaarfile-1.4.7', ext: 'aar')`. when i build i had an error in the string.xml of one of the aar file. So i manually change the file name to .zip then attracted it and fixed the string.xml and compress it using mac default compression and then rename again to aar. Then now the new problem started. When the gradle build started, i got an error that the manifest file in not found in the build folder. But the file is there just that there was a subdir created under myaarfile with the same name. As for mysecondaarfile seems to be fine since i didnt extract and compress it again. Is there something wrong re-compressing the aar file  ? Thanks in advance.